# How to queue jquery commands

Tags: jquery

With this code:

```
<body>
    <div id="a1" style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black; margin:10px;"></div>
    <div id="a2" style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black; margin:10px;"></div>

    <script>
        i = 1;
        $("#a" + i).hover(function(){
            $("#a" + i).css("background-color", "grey");
        }, function(){
            $("#a" + i).css("background-color", "black");
        });

        i = 2;
        $("#a" + i).hover(function(){
            $("#a" + i).css("background-color", "grey");
        }, function(){
            $("#a" + i).css("background-color", "black");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I cannot receive the hover effect for each element, when I over mouse on the first, the second element changed. I think jquery not same as javascript about the sequence of commands, may be the hover for the first still not run yet. I can use queue function to order the command?

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It will make it much easier for you, and others, to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the handlers are assigned on load, and executed well after that point when the `mouseenter` event fires. Because of that, `i` will *always* be `2`.

A better method is to attach the same handler to both elements, and use the `this` keyword in the handler to relate the logic to the element which raised the event. Try this:

```
<div id="a1" class="foo"></div>
<div id="a2" class="foo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.foo').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    });
</script>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2k5Lt/)

Note that by using classes on your elements, you can place the styling information in to a CSS stylesheet for a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

At the time function will be executed the value of `i` will be `2`, So using `this` instead of selectors will help you

```
i = 1;
$("#a" + i).hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
});

i = 2;
$("#a" + i).hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
});
```

And I think you are repeating code you can write like bellow.

```
for(var i=1;i<=2;i++){
    $("#a" + i).hover(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
        }, function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
        });
}
```

Comment: The functions close around `i`, which cause it's value to be `2` by the time they get invoked.